# I am not able to make a select inside another

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    id, name, price, category, url, image1
FROM 
    `Products_items` 
WHERE 
        active = 'y' 
    and stockCount >= 1
ORDER BY 
    views DESC
```

Above is my select, but I need `category_url` in categories table, how can I get it using only one query?

Comment: INNER JOIN should do the trick read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: you should provide the table definition for Products_items and categories.
Hint: You should name your tables in singular. You will nearly always have multiple items in one table to plural from is redundant and sigular makes the name easier to read.